# How to enforce specific values for the parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
# GET /homeworks/1
# GET /homeworks/1.json
def show
    params.permit(:id => [])
end
```

I want to enforce some specific values for 'id' parameter. If the value of 'id' is not "1" or "2", it should not render the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to implement such limitations using the routes. In your `routes.rb`,

```
get 'homeworks/:id', :to=>'my_controller#show', :constraints => {:id => /^[12]$/}
```

`/^[12]$/` is the regular expression for "either 1 or 2". So for `GET /homeworks/3` it would give a routing error.

Comment: great. How can I add such constraints into this style: resources :homeworks

Answer (score 0):

```
if @homework.id > 2
render :text => "unable to render view"
else
render 'view'
end
```